# How to pass arguments to a spark job main class using gcloud?

Tags: java, apache-spark, gcloud

I have following gcloud spark job command.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster=clusterName \
--region=regionName \
--class=clazzName \
--files=fileName \
--jars=jarPath
```

The main class `clazzName` has following behaviour

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length==0)
    //do something

    if(args.length==1)
    //do something using args[0]
}
```

How shall I pass `args[0]=foo` to main class in the spark job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments by adding them to the end of your argument, more info can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/spark).

In your case, to get `foo` in your application you would need to do:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster=clusterName \
--region=regionName \
--class=clazzName \
--files=fileName \
--jars=jarPath \
-- foo
```

If you wanted to have 2 arguments: `foo` and `bar` (so your `args` array would have length == 2) you would simply add it after the first one, separated by a space

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster=clusterName \
--region=regionName \
--class=clazzName \
--files=fileName \
--jars=jarPath \
-- foo bar
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The space between -- and foo is important, was missing that in my initial attempts.